# TPL Data flow giving .Net referenced assemblies in output

Tags: visual-studio-2013, setup-project, tpl-dataflow

I am using Visual studio 2013. I added Microsoft.TPL.Dataflow 4.5.24 from Nuget Package Manager solution for project in VS. I also having Setup for this project.

When i rebuild the Setup Project All the .net referenced libraries(System.IO, System.Linq and etc.,) are also come in output directory. If i remove the TPL.dataflow then the problem wont exist.

I need to use this library for my project. Please Help me to remove Referenced libraries in the output of setup project

Comment: What problem???

Comment: In any case, you should use the `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow`, not the very old `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow`. That package was used in the initial phases and abandoned when Dataflow became a regular .NET component

Comment: I am using System.Threading.Task.Dataflow which I got from Nuget. I guess all the dll is rewritten lol System.IO.well to work dataflow ell. That's why it is coming output of the project.

Comment: I couldn't find it in 4.5 framework. That's why I added through package

Comment: .NET assemblies are delivered as packages since 4.0 I think, definitely since 4.5.